# android 14 update

Tags: android, eclipse

After updating to SDK14 (Android), I get that err:

> No repository found at
>   jar:file:/D:/Originals/Others/eclipse/plugins/net.sf.fjep.fatjar_0.0.31.jar!/.

I close it and try to compile my own project, it's worked on previous SDK.
But now when I want to compile my project, I get this err:

> your project contains error please fix them before running your
>   application

And a lot errors in console.

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely have to remove your previous `build.xml` file, then run the `android` command-line utility to update your project. This will create a new `build.xml` file compatible with the newer SDK and platform tools.

Comment: Where I can find 'build.xml'?

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse: right buttom over the project folder and choose in the menu: Android / fix project